# Zend Framework 1.10 Override Class Call?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework-modules

I think I am trying to be overly clever. If it works, yay. If not, no worries.

I want my application to be as modular as possible. At the moment I have just a products module but from experience I know I might want a categories module as well, in which products will be children of. Whilst the categories module does not exist I want calls to, for example, Products_Forms_NewProduct to load **that** form. When the categories module is dropped into the application I want it to be automatically detected and forward any calls for, for example, Products_Forms_NewProduct to Categories_Forms_NewProduct.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Whilst this would be possible, I think you might be heading down the wrong path here. Why would the presence of a categories module require a totally new product form? Surely you would just need some fields to be added to that form for selecting of categories?

Comment: I want things to be just drop and go. I want a standard products form (name, description, etc). If I have categories, then I will want to *extend* that form to include a parent category field. If I have an ecart setup, then I might want to *extend* it again (price?, etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for dependency injection IMO. But I'd suggest having a class that would modify the form appropriately. Like a form-plugin. This is no case of extension, but rather composition. I'd go with something alon those lines:

```
// say in Form_NewProduct's init()
$this->addPlugin(new Form_Plugin_Category());
$this->addSubform(new Form_NewProduct_ProductSubform());

//in plugin or in form directly
if (class_exists('Form_NewProduct_CategorySubform')) {
    $this->_form->addSubform(new Form_NewProduct_CategorySubform());
}
```